# 3d line (Vector) drawing in Android?

Tags: java, android, 3d

I have a simple idea:
I want to draw a line in 3d space (the screen). The line will have a 3d direction and magnitude (length). I would then like to append a new line (vector) onto the last, and another, and another, etc.

I would like to show these lines in a 3d wire frame that serves as a visual reference to the vectors contained within. I would like each Vector would have a label showing its magnitude.

Is this feasible with the existing Android graphics/3d framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called opengl, and it can not only draw you points and lines, but also triangles!!!